# How to use two Magic Keyboards simultaneously?

Tags: keyboard

I am trying double keyboard setup. I have been able to connect both keyboards using the method described in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/119560/146612).

However, the problem is that using a modifier key in one keyboard and pressing a letter in the other one is not working. I guess that Magic Keyboard is not sending anything when you press a modifier key unless you press a letter as well.

Can you think of any solutions/hacks/etc. to this problem? That is, is there a way to use a modifier key from one keyboard and use a letter (number, symbol, etc.) from another keyboard?

Comment: https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements/issues/1216 I know this doesn't have any answers, but it might be good to keep up with. Seems to be the same issue.

Comment: This answer is about two mouses (mice?) but the premise and answer is the same in this case.  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/287612/119271

Comment: Is there a fix for this?